# Sum of closed subspaces in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $M,N$ subspaces of $\ell^2$ such that 
$$M=\text{cl}(\text{span}\{e_{2j}|j \in \mathbb{N}\})$$ 
$$N=\text{cl}(\text{span}\{e_{2j}+ \frac{1}{j}e_{2j-1}|j \in \mathbb{N} \})$$

Prove that $x=(1,0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{3},0,\ldots,0,\frac{1}{n},0,\ldots) \notin M+N$

I don't know if it helps but I proved that $M+N$ is dense in $\ell^2$.

If $x \in M+N$ then $\exists x_n \in M $ and $y_n \in N$ such that $y_n+x_n \to x \Leftrightarrow \|x_n+y_n-x\|_2 \to0$

In  general I am confused in how a sequence of finite linear combinations will be. (I am not sure how to take the right indices)

Can someone explain to me in which way can a sequence of finite linear combinations be represented correctly and help me reach a contradiction?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to prove that x belongs to M+N maybe? Because if it is realy dense then x would be in that sum

Comment: the exercise in my instructor's notes says to prove that in does not belong to $M+N$

Comment: I know i already thought that because of denseness , $x$ must belong to $M+N$

Comment: But according to this exercise i must prove that it doesn't

Comment: Is the sum is algebraic sum or is it taken with closure?

Comment: it is taken with closure..$M,N$ are closures of linear spans of the elements i wrote in the question

Comment: I think that's a mistake. But let's wait for other comments.

Comment: I think you are right..!

Comment: The $x$ in question is certainly in the closure of $M+N$, but it is not in $M+N$. If that were the case, you could write $x=x_M+x_N$, with $x_M\in M$ and $x_N\in N$.  But what would $x_M$ and $x_N$ have to be?

Comment: if we take two sets $A+B$ is the sum of their closures equal to the closure of the sum?

Comment: That's not true.  Consider $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:xy=1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x=0\}$.  These two sets are closed, but their sum $A+B$ is not closed.

Comment: is it because $ A+B=\{(x,\frac{1}{x}+y)|x,y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ so we have a problem at points near $ (0,0)$?

Comment: $A+B=\mathbb R^2\setminus B$, which is open.  But back to the question at hand:  Try assuming $x=x_M+x_N$ with $x_M\in M$ and $x_N\in N$ and try to determine what $x_M$ and $x_N$ are.  That's how you'll get your contradiction.

Comment: $x_N$ and $x_M$ will be represented  each one as a finite linear combination.

Comment: but $x_N$  for instance is in the closure of span{....} so how will it be represented? it must be a limit of a sequence of finite linear combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $x \in M+N$, then there are sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e_{2n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\left(e_{2n}+\frac{1}{n} e_{2n-1} \right) = x,
$$ and both sums converge independently.

Comment: I have question : In general if $M$ is an orthogonal set of vectors in $l^2$, is any vector in $cl ~ span (M)$ represented in same way , as you did ? infinite sigma...

Comment: @Ashkan Yes they can. Since $A = \overline{\text{span}(M)}$ is a closed subspace, it's also a Hilbert space. Because $M$ can be turned into an orthonormal base of $A$ simply by normalizing, you would have for any $x \in A$ that $x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\langle x, v_n \rangle}{\lVert v_n \rVert^2} v_n$ where $M=\{v_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: +1 for comment...,  also  can we generalize this idea to all $l^p$ spaces?

Comment: @Ashkan I'm not sure. There is no notion of orthogonality in Banach spaces, so you would have to employ an entirely different argument. Maybe if $M  = \{ v_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ were very "simple" vectors as in finite linear combinations of $e_n$ you could use the dual space of $l^p$. That is for example if $v_n = e_n$, you could use the linear functionals $l_n$ defined by $l_n(x) = x_n$. Then for a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\text{span}(M)$ converging to $x \in A$ simply set $a_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} l_k(x_n)$. But I'm not sure if that guarantees that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e_k$ converges.

Comment: @Ashkan Maybe you should make a post about this.